# Keys whose values extend V

Tags: typescript

For example:

```
interface Foo {
  a: string
  b: string
  c: number
}
```

How can I define `KeysOf<T, V>` such that `KeysOf<Foo, string>` gives `"a" | "b"` and `KeysOf<Foo, number>` gives `"c"`?

I tried `type KeysOf<T, V> = T[infer K] extends V ? K : never`, but TypeScript does not allow `infer` on the left operand of `extends`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a mapped type and a conditional type:

```
interface Foo {
   a: string
   b: string
   c: number
}


type KeyOf<T, V> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends V ? P : never
}[keyof T]

type S = KeyOf<Foo, string> //"a" | "b"
type N = KeyOf<Foo, number> //"c"
```